# Install latest `kate` on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, kate

Can someone suggest how to install the latest version `kate` editor on Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed it from default 14.04 repository, ie,

`sudo apt-get install kate`

The default version I got is: `Kate Version 3.13.3, Using KDE Development Platform 4.13.3`. This version works ok, but there are some features just not functioning properly, like tab colors, etc., which is an annoyance from an otherwise great editor.

So I wonder how to install the latest version of `kate` in my machine to see if those issues may away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable Kubuntu backports repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Kate:

```
sudo apt-get install kate
```

You may find more info here: http://pkgs.org/download/kate

Comment: thanks, I now have `Kate Version 3.14.13, Using KDE Development Platform 4.14.13` - seems like the new version has been install.

Comment: To me its a bad habbit just mentioning a PPA W/O any background. Let's add some more information  as  seen on "Kubuntuwire" 

_KDE 4.14.3 Bugfix release for Kubuntu Trusty (14.04.3 LTS) is now available._   http://www.wire.kubuntu.org/?p=419 dated 7th November 2015

Comment: @ellisistfroh, Please elaborate a bit more on the background you require.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh., [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) should've been linked as SSL (HTTPS)? :o

**Kate**, *the MDI text editor application* can now be downloaded as **AppImage** - and run without installation, from [kate-editor.org](https://kate-editor.org/get-it/); although it's (also) available in Ubuntu 17.10:

```
~$ apt list kate
Listing... Done
kate/artful 4:17.04.3-0ubuntu1 amd64
```

The support forum (& web site) are @[discourse.appimage.org](https://discourse.appimage.org/)